# C# Winforms multiple panels with individual autoscroll

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, autoscroll

I have three panels(top, middle, bottom) on a tabpage(Size:490x470, AutoScroll:True, AutoScrollMinSize: 450,50). Enabled Autoscroll for all the panels(Size:450x100, AutoScroll:True, AutoScrollMinSize: 450,50). See the attached picture.[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WylJs.png)

When i resize the form, the scrollbar doesn't appear for individual panels.Refer the attached picture. [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I8Gq.png)

How can to configure the panels so that the panels have separate scroll bars.

Comment: It doesn't look like that the size of those three panels is modified. Your TabControl (or its container, or both) is, probably, not anchored/docked, so it doesn't shrink when the Form's size is changed. Use the `Anchor` property to redefine the behaviour of these control when a container is resized.

Comment: Thank You @Jimi . I have anchored the panels to top, left and right. Now, the panels are showing have scroll bars. Thanks.